# TypeORM - duplicate key value violation

Tags: orm, nestjs, typeorm

Let's say I have a simple TypeORM entity like this:

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratorColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Employee {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    Name: string;
}
```

It all works fine as long as I do not touch database manually. If I enter a record manually, the Entity will not be able to check the last current `id` from the table and throws error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

For example:

1. `Employee Entity` creates two records by itself.
2. I have two records in my database, last record has `id 2`
3. I create third record in the database manually, it has `id 3`
4. Afterwards, when `Employee Entity` runs, it does not = create another record, since it wants to use `id 3`, but I added that manually already.
5. I am getting error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`
6. When `Employee Entity` runs again, it works, because it tries to save another record under `id 4` already which is available.

So how can I ensure, that `Employee Entity` checks the last id from the database and then saves the next record with incremental `id`?

Thank you

Comment: Can you change your id from incremental (number) to [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)? PS: It's recommended to use pseudo-random ids rather than simple incremental for security reasons.

Comment: Hi @CarloCorradini, thank you for the advice. If it is better to use pseudo-random ids anyways, then I can go this way.

Comment: Nice! Remember: ```@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')```

Answer (score 5):

In TypeORM the decorator `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` creates a primary column which the value will be generated using a sequence. Every time you add a new record on the database it uses the `nextval` of the sequence set for that column. Assuming you are using PostgreSQL (I believe for other databases it would be similar) you have an Employee table

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.Employee (
    number serial NOT NULL,
    nane varchar NULL
);
```

And because the decorator `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` a sequence `employee_id_seq` will also be created. You can check its latest value by running

```sql
select last_value from employee_id_seq;
```

When your application creates two records it uses the sequence to generate the new ids, changing the `employee_id_seq` `last_value` value. With two records in the database the new last_value will be updated to 2.

If you create a third record manually passing id = 3

```sql
INSERT INTO public.Employee (id, name) VALUES(3, 'new_name')
```

the sequence will not be used, and its last_value will be 2. Next time your application tries to insert a new record it executes an insert without passing the id, because it relies on the sequence to generate the value, like this

```sql
INSERT INTO public.Employee (name) VALUES('another_name');
```

or (not sure how TypeORM handles it exactly)

```sql
INSERT INTO public.Employee (id, name) VALUES(nextval('employee_id_seq', 'another_name')
```

The SQL above will use the `last_value` from the sequence and add 1, resulting in 3 and a `duplicate key violation`. So if you add a record manually you don't need set the id manually, you can run

```sql
INSERT INTO public.Employee (name) VALUES('name')
```

and the id will be auto-generated using the sequence.

Comment: Thank you V. Lovato for the great explanation, it really helped me! Now I know how it works behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had wrongly defined a relationship. It was supposed to be `@ManyToOne`, but I had `@OneToOne`.
This makes sense because a OneToOne should have one instance for each entity, Therefore the sequence generator gives the same id for every tried insert, causing the error as it's not unique for subsequent saves. I think TypeORM should give a different error message, took me 2 days to figure out.